# script + particle system don't work unless some other game object is selected in the inspector

Tags: unity, c#, particles

I have an object "SEA" emitting particles, controlled by a script using emissionRate, emissionSpeed etc.

When the particles collide with the SKY GameObject, another GameObject called "CLOUD" is instantiated. It contains a "RAIN" script and a "WATER" script. On instantiate, CLOUD is supposed to start emitting new particles, reducing the amount of stored water accordingly.

The issue is nothing happens (no emission, no water decrease) unless I manually click on another game object in the Inspector (could be anything, a text, a 3D Object etc.). This way the particle system starts working and the water starts depleting correctly every second.

I tried different approaches:

1. disable and re-enable the CLOUD gameobject (in awake and start).

   ```
   void Awake()
   {
       cloudPrefab.gameObject.SetActive(false);
   }

   void Start()
   {
       cloudPrefab.gameObject.SetActive(true);
   }
   ```
2. switch the focus on another object. This way it works (partially) but there is a huge decrease in performance, so it's not a good solution.

   ```
   void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
   {
       int numCollisionEvents = psEvap.GetCollisionEvents(other, collisionEvents);
       int i = 0;

       while (i < numCollisionEvents)
       {
           Vector3 pos = collisionEvents[i].intersection;
           Vector3 force = collisionEvents[i].velocity;// * 10;
           Instantiate(cloudPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
           Selection.activeObject = other;

           i++;
       }
   }
   ```
3. create a InvokeRepeating method that selects a different object every
   x sec. It doesn't work + same decrease in performance.

   ```
   void Start()
   {
       InvokeRepeating("selectSomething", 1, 1);

   }
   void selectSomething()
   {
       Selection.activeObject = daysText;
   }
   ```

I'm really out of options. I think this could be a bug in Unity.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
public class Rain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem psRain;
    public List<ParticleCollisionEvent> collisionEvents;
    public int attackValue = 1;
    Water water;

    //[Range(0f, 500f)]
    //public float emissionRate = 30;

    //[Range(1f, 50f)]
    //public float emissionSpeed = 1;

    //[Range(1.0f, 100f)]
    //public float particleLife;

    //public GameObject cloudPrefab;

 
    void Start()
    {

        psRain = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        collisionEvents = new List<ParticleCollisionEvent>();
        water = GetComponent<Water>();

        //emissionRate = 1;
        //emissionSpeed = 5;
        //evaporationPoint = water.waterMax / 1000;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        //SceneView.FrameLastActiveSceneView();
        //SceneView.FrameLastActiveSceneView();



        //var main = psRain.main;
        //var emission = psRain.emission;

        //main.maxParticles = Mathf.RoundToInt(emissionRate * 1000);
        //main.startSpeed = emissionSpeed;
        //particleLife = 20.0f;
        //main.startLifetime = particleLife;

        if (water.waterCurrent > 0)
        {

            //emission.rateOverTime = emissionRate;
            psRain.Play();
            water.waterCurrent -= psRain.particleCount;
            //Level.cluodsInGame += psEvap.particleCount/10;

        }

        if (water.waterCurrent <= 0)
        {
            psRain.Stop();
        }
    }

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
    {
        int numCollisionEvents = psRain.GetCollisionEvents(other, collisionEvents);
        int i = 0;

        while (i < numCollisionEvents)
        {
            Water waterSource = other.GetComponent<Water>();

            if (waterSource != null)
            {
                Vector3 pos = collisionEvents[i].intersection;
                Vector3 force = collisionEvents[i].velocity;// * 10;
                //rb.AddForce(force);
                waterSource.TakeDamage(attackValue);

            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    int GetAliveParticles()
    {
        ParticleSystem.Particle[] particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[psRain.particleCount];
        return psRain.GetParticles(particles);
    }
}



public class Water : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waterMax;
    public float waterCurrent;

    public TMP_Text waterText;
    bool isDead;



    void Start()
    {
        if (tag == "water")
        {
            waterCurrent = waterMax;
        }

        if (tag == "sea")
        {
            waterCurrent = waterMax;
            //waterCurrent = float.PositiveInfinity;

        }

        if (tag == "cloud")
        {
            waterCurrent = 10000;
        }

        //if (tag == "sky")
        //{
        //    waterText.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        //}
    }


    void Update()
    {
        waterText.text = waterCurrent.ToString();

        if (waterCurrent <= 0)
        {
            waterCurrent = 0;
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        waterCurrent += amount;

        if (waterCurrent <= 0 && !isDead)
        {
            //StartCoroutine(Death());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the rain and water scripts? Have you tried playing with the Culling Mode selected on your cloud particle system?

Comment: i added the 2 scripts. Yes i tried the culling mode,. same results. the problem is not only the particle system but the game behavior itself. it seems the inspector loses focus so the scripts are not executed anymore, unless. when the focus comes back everything returns to normal.